# Method used to calculate average time spent

Tags: statistics, average

I need to calculate the average time spent on a single article.

My data set ranges from a few seconds up to an hour.

[Dataset Summary .png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbA88.png)

I'm currently using mean to calculate the average but was wondering if there are any other more appropriate ways to compute the average?

Comment: What about the median ?

Comment: The data are heavily skewed so the median would be more representative

Comment: "More representative" of what? The _most common_ thing is to spend less than a minute. Does that mean fast readers or useless search results? The fundamental question is what you want to learn from the data and why.